# How can i compare the ibm watson speech to a specific string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, watson

Please guide me how can i compare the speech or transcribe from microphone to a string in if else statement. below code is not going inside the if statement. thank you

```
var stream = recognizeMic({
    token: token,
    objectMode: false, // send objects instead of text
    extractResults: false, // convert {results: [{alternatives:[...]}], result_index: 0} to {alternatives: [...], index: 0}
    format: false // optional - performs basic formatting on the results such as capitals an periods

});
stream.setEncoding('utf8');
stream.on('data', (data) => {

    console.log(data);
    var txt = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(txt);
    if (txt === "example") {
        console.log("Success");
        window.open("https://www.example.com")
    }
});
stream.on('error', function(err) {
console.log(err);
});
//document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = stream.stop.bind(stream);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
}
```

Comment: Please, reformat the code on the question!

Comment: The proper way of doing this would be to get the data you need from the JSON. Some research into JSON will show you how you to do this. As a quick alternative, although it's a terrible one, you can change `txt === "example"` to `txt.includes("example")` which will check if the word `"example"` is anywhere inside of the variable txt.